# prevent scroll top from confirm jquery / prevent scroll top from remove product from mini cart in magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery, scroll

In Magento 2, I've seen that when we click on the button remove a product from the mini cart, we will be scrolled to the top of the site.

[image]

I've see that this one is because of `<a href="#">` tag, and replace with `<a href="javascript:;">`.

[image]

But that isn't enough, it still has the problem, so I've debugged it deeper and found that this `confirm` from jquery have responsibility for this.

 I just need to remove that `confirm` code, and it won't scroll top anymore.

[image]

But unlucky that I can't find any solution to prevent the scroll to top from the `confirm` jquery library.

Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've debug deeper and found that this is because when you click on remove product button, magento modal use js to add `_has-modal` class to `<body>` and also this activate some css related to `_has-modal` class.

For specific, this line is responsible for scroll top problem:

```
body._has-modal {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

So i've create a css to override that part and it resolved the problem.

```
body._has-modal {
    overflow: initial;
}
```

[image]

Hope it help someone who have this problem too.